# Quasi-Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Sequence $(x_n)$ is called *quasi-Cauchy* if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|x_{n+1}-x_n|=0.$
I need help proving the following theorems:

1. Quasi-Cauchy sequence of real numbers is Cauchy if and only if it has exactly one cluster point.
2. Sequence of real numbers is Cauchy if and only if every subsequence is quasi-Cauchy.

I understand the implications to the right (they are trivial), but have trouble proving the opposite way. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Any sequence of real numbers which has exactly one cluster point is a Cauchy.
2. If $(a_n ) $ is not Cauchy sequence then it is not convergent. Hence there exists a subseqences $(x_{n_k } )$, $(y_{m_k} )$ of $(a_n )$ such that $x_{n_k }\to x, y_{n_k }\to y$ and $x\neq y $ and $n_k \neq m_k $ for all $k.$ Consider a subsequence $(z_k)$ of $(a_n)$ defined by $z_{2k-1} =x_{n_k} , z_{2k} =y_{m_k}.$ Then $$\lim_{k\to\infty} |z_k -z_{k+1}|=\lim_{k\to\infty} |x_{n_k} -y_{m_k}|=|x-y|\neq 0$$
   hence the subsequence $(z_k)$ is not quasi-Cauchy.

Comment: For the R-to-L of 1., your answer is just a statement of what needs to be proved.

Comment: 1 is false. The sequence $x_{2n}=n,x_{2n+1}=1/n$ has exactly one (finite) cluster point, but is not Cauchy.

Comment: @Wojowu .Q 1. is " If S is quasi-Cauchy then [[ S converges iff S has exactly one cluster point.]].".. English grammar is slippery.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I was refering solely to the answer. It's not true that "Any sequence of real numbers which has exactly one cluster point is a Cauchy."

Comment: @Wojowu   OHHH. ... U R Right...........

Answer (score 6):

For the R-to-L of 1.  suppose $(x_n)_n$ is quasi-Cauchy and has a cluster point $p$  but $(x_n)_n$ is not Cauchy. Then $(x_n)_n$ does not converge to $p,$ so there exists $r>0$ such that the set $$S=\{n: |x_n-p|\geq r\}$$ is infinite.

Take $n_0$ such that $n> n_0\implies |x_n-x_{n+1}|<r/3.$ Now the set $$T=\{n:|x_n-p|< r/3\}$$ is also infinite because $p$ is a cluster point of $(x_n)_n$.

For $n_0<n\in T$ there exists $n'> n$ with $n'\in S.$ So for $n_0<n\in T$ let $f(n)$ be the least $n'>n$ such that $n'\in S.$

Observe that the set $U=\{f(n): n_0<n\in T\}$ is infinite .   We have  $$m\in U\implies (\;|x_m-p|\geq r \;\land \;|x_m-x_{m-1}|<r/3 \;\land\; |x_{m-1}-p|<r\;).$$  So for $m\in U$ we have $$x_m\in V=[p-4r/3,p-2r/3]\;\cup \; [p+2r/3, p+4r/3].$$ But there are infinitely many $m\in U,$ so $(x_n)_n$ must have a cluster point $q\in V$, and obviously  $q\ne p.$

Summary: A quasi-Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_n$ with exactly one cluster point $p$ must be convergent to $p$, otherwise $(x_n)_n$ would have another cluster point $q$.

Comment: By some small modifications we can see that if a quasi-Cauchy sequence has 2 or more cluster points then there is a bounded interval containing infinitely many  cluster points.